# Godot Server creation within Client

Tags: networking, godot, gdscript

**I am trying to make a Mini-Game Library with some multiplayer games. I would like to do it so everyone can just create a lobby which runs on their PC and other people can connect to it.**

I am really unsure on how to approach it because I'm not experienced with Godots High-Level Networking and everything else network related I did was in Node.js with a public server always running and handeling all the connections.

I would just like some tips on how to start setting something like this up.

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: My understanding is for people on different networks to connect over the internet they either need to set up their own server (fairly technical), or you need to provide some for them. For LAN games it's much easier to set up since you just need to connect with other devices on the same network. For example in minecraft it's easy to play with someone over LAN but for playing with people on different networks you need to pay for something like minecraft realms or host your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the example(s) on https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects of which [/networking/multiplayer_bomber](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects/tree/master/networking/multiplayer_bomber) fits your needs best I guess